# Convert DB response from object to array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have the following schema:

```js
const mySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
   name: String,
   subscribers: [ { name: String } ] 
})
const myModel = mongoose.model('User', mySchema, 'users')
```

and I have this code in one of my controllers:

```js
const allOfHisSubscribers = await myModel.findById(req.params.id).select('subscribers')
```

I want the database response of the await `myModel.findByid` call to be:

```js
[
 { name: 'x' },
 { name: 'y' },
 { name: 'z' },
]
```

However, the code above is returning:

```js
{
   subscribers: [
     { name: 'x' },
     { name: 'y' },
     { name: 'z' },
   ]
}
```

I don't want the JavaScript way of doing it, I know you can use something like `Array.prototype.map` to get the result, but I am using a middleware, so I can only use the Mongoose or MongoDB way of doing it (if possible).

Comment: I believe this is correct behavior, [docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html). `.select()` is worked as projection, it would also return the field (name). If you want the array only: `const subscribers =  allOfHisSubscribers.subscribers;`.

Comment: you can use [aggregation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) query to customize your response, but i would suggest you don't use aggregation to just customize simple thing this is simple in JS just need to access by a key `subscribers`,

Comment: yes, it's my mistake, I should have included the exact code I am writing. I can't use JavaScript directly because I'm  using an express middleware that finds and awaits the docs, I have only a space to write an argument like `expressMiddleware((req)=>myModel.findById(req.params.id))`,

Comment: this one https://www.npmjs.com/package/setdoc

Comment: @turivishal, I'll take a look at aggregate and I'll see how to implement it, but I hope this isn't going to skip the schema validations and middlewares

Comment: @turivishal, hey I have read the aggregation, I think it's simply stupid, bur I could not find which operator to use among all of those options, is it the $group operator? any help :=

Comment: 1) `$match` to match your id  2) `$unwind` operator to deconstruct the `subscribers` array and 3) `$replaceRoot` to replace `subscribers` object to root